# Вывести результат формы в <iframe>

Tags: php, html, form, iframe, submit

Как можно вывести результат обработки формы php-файлом в фрейм, который находиться на странице с формой, при этом обновляя только фрейм, но не страницу?

```
<form action='gg.php' method='post'>
    <textarea name="code" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
<iframe src="gg.php" width="468" height="60" align="right">

</iframe>
```

Вот что внутри gg.php:

```
<?php

$raw_code = $_POST['code'];
eval($raw_code);

?>
```

Comment: _"обновляя только фрейм, но не страницу"_ - а почему именно фрейм? Без обновления страницы можно использовать AJAX + JQiery, обновляя данные в конкретном теге `<div>`

Comment: та уже додумался до этого

Comment: Ого, как долго вы не отвечали  )